# WPF Menu - Allow specific control to be enabled inside disabled menuitem

Tags: wpf, menu

I have a Menu binded to a collection of models.
MenuItem command is binded to the model command.

I've redefined the SubMenuItem control template to add a ToggleButton in it.
This ToggleButton allow the user to specify the MenuItem to be a "favorite". I want this ToggleButton to be always enabled.

```
 <ControlTemplate x:Key="{x:Static MenuItem.SubmenuItemTemplateKey}" TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
    <Grid x:Name="PART_Conteneur" Background="Transparent">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="Star" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ToggleButton x:Name="PART_StarButton" Style="{DynamicResource VerticalToolBarMenuStarToggleButtonStyle}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="2,0,0,0" />
        <Border x:Name="Border" BorderThickness="1" Grid.Column="1" Padding="0,2,0,2">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="Icon" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="Shortcut" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="13" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                
                <ContentPresenter x:Name="Icon" Margin="6,0,6,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="0" ContentSource="Icon" Width="20" />
                <ContentPresenter x:Name="HeaderHost" Grid.Column="1" ContentSource="Header" RecognizesAccessKey="True" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                <TextBlock x:Name="InputGestureText" Grid.Column="2" Text="{TemplateBinding InputGestureText}" Margin="5,2,0,2" DockPanel.Dock="Right" />
            </Grid>
        </Border>
    </Grid>
    
    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="ButtonBase.Command" Value="{x:Null}" />
        <Trigger Property="Icon" Value="{x:Null}">
            <Setter TargetName="Icon" Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden" />
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsHighlighted" Value="true">
            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Border" Value="{DynamicResource ItemSelectedBrushKey}" />
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="Border">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                        <GradientStop Color="#FF888888" Offset="0" />
                        <GradientStop Color="Transparent" Offset="1" />
                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
            <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="{DynamicResource DisableOpacity}" />
        </Trigger>
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>
```

When the MenuItem is disabled (Command CanExecute returns False), the ToggleButton is disabled too.

How can I enable the ToggleButton only ?

**EDIT:**

I managed to accomplish my needs by adding a new ItemsControl in the TopLevelHeader template popup that will be containing the ToggleButtons:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="VerticalToolBarMenuTopLevelHeaderTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
    <Border x:Name="Border">
        <Grid>
            <ContentPresenter Margin="6,3,20,3" ContentSource="Header" RecognizesAccessKey="True" HorizontalAlignment="Right" />
            <Popup x:Name="Popup" Placement="Bottom" IsOpen="{TemplateBinding IsSubmenuOpen}" AllowsTransparency="True" Focusable="False" PopupAnimation="Fade" StaysOpen="True">
                <Border x:Name="SubmenuBorder" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" BorderThickness="1" Background="{DynamicResource ToolBarPopupBackgroundBrushKey}" 
                        BorderBrush="{DynamicResource PopupBorderBrushKey}">
                    <ScrollViewer CanContentScroll="True" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding }">
                                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <Grid Height="25">
                                            <ToggleButton x:Name="PART_StarButton" Style="{DynamicResource VerticalToolBarMenuStarToggleButtonStyle}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="2,0,0,0" />
                                        </Grid>                                            
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                            </ItemsControl>
                            <StackPanel IsItemsHost="True" KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Cycle" Grid.Column="1" />
                        </Grid>                            
                    </ScrollViewer>
                </Border>
            </Popup>
        </Grid>
    </Border>
    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsSuspendingPopupAnimation" Value="true">
            <Setter TargetName="Popup" Property="PopupAnimation" Value="None" />
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsHighlighted" Value="true">
            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent" />
            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Border" Value="{DynamicResource ItemSelectedBrushKey}" />
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger SourceName="Popup" Property="AllowsTransparency" Value="True">
            <Setter TargetName="SubmenuBorder" Property="CornerRadius" Value="0,0,4,4" />
            <Setter TargetName="SubmenuBorder" Property="Padding" Value="0,0,0,3" />
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="{DynamicResource DisableOpacity}" />
        </Trigger>
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you cannot do this.
When CanExecute returns false, then the IsEnabled property takes on the same value.
And IsEnabled = false disables not only the element itself, but also everything nested in it.
This behavior is defined in UIElement and cannot be changed.

Comment: Ok thanks. So is there any way to achieve this kind of behavior without recreating a whole menu control on my own ? Maybe the ToggleButton could be outside his nested MenuItem visual tree, but I don't know how.

Comment: It depends on the required logic.
Your explanation is not enough to fully understand it.
The command for a MenuItem performs the action taken when the item is selected.
But you obviously need something different.


An element consists of several nested user interface elements.
Explain how the command relates to the nested UI elements?

Comment: I've just found a workaround, and edited my question. For answering your question, the command is related to the MenuItem (enabled, disabled, execute action) as it is intended to be, but the toggle button is not linked to this command. It juste need to be near the MenuItem, but not related to its command.